# Using multiple instances of setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dztGA/22/

**The goal:** Essentially, I'm trying to have 2 discrete timers on the same page that can be destroyed and re-created on mouseover/mouseout (pause), or on manual progression (restart).

**The problem:** What my jsFiddle's single timer will illustrate is that when I click "Stop Timer", my setInterval  (stored in variable t) seems to have multiple instances albeit being destroyed with clearInterval(t). This becomes apparent when I click "Restart Timer" and it seems to have 2+ independent timers as illustrated by the quick increment.

**A caveat:** I have done as much research on SO as I can, but because I'll be having 2 different sliders on the page, I can't use any "clear all timers" methods, so I tried storing each in a variable.

I hope that's clear. Thanks for the view.

Comment: Can't dupe; Chrome 14 under Ubuntu--works fine. Although referring to `window.t` and `t` depending on where you are gives me the heebie-jeebies.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton , I thought calling window.method(t) inferred clearing object "window"'s parameter "t"! Much appreciated for the insight.

Comment: If I click "restart timer" repeatedly, without clicking anything else, the timer will run out of control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix your current issue: Add `clearInterval(window.t)` at the `onclick` function of the reset button.

A method to be able to have **multiple** timers. This requires a certain structure, though.
**Fiddle (6 timers!): http://jsfiddle.net/dztGA/27/**

```
(function(){ //Anonymous function, to not leak variables to the global scope
    var defaultSpeed = 3000; //Used when missing
    var timerSpeed = [500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000];

    var intervals = [];
    function increase(i){
        return function(){
            var elem = $("#count"+i);
            elem.text(parseFloat(elem.text()) + 1);
        }
    }
    function clear(i){
        return function(){
            clearInterval(intervals[i]);
        }
    }
    function restart(i){ //Start AND restart
        return function(){
            clear(i)();
            increase(i)();
            intervals[i] = setInterval(increase(i), timerSpeed[i]||defaultSpeed);
        }
    }
    // Manual increment
    $('input[name=increment]').each(function(i){
        $(this).click(function(){
            restart(i)();
            increase(i)();
        });
    });

    // Clear timer on "Clear"
    $('input[name=clear]').each(function(i) {
        $(this).click(clear(i));
    });

    // Restart timer on "Restart"
    $('input[name=reset]').each(function(i) {
        $(this).click(restart(i));

        //Optionally, activate each timer:
        increase(i)();
    });
})();
```

Comment: My understanding was that I was calling the .clearInterval method, on the window object, and therefore clearInterval(window.t) was implied. Anyway, it works so far, so thanks very much!

Comment: Updated answer. You've stated that you originally wanted to support multiple timers ;)

Comment: I'm literally programming that right now - thank you so much for going out of your way to help guide my next step!

Comment: I really like your semantic names, keeping it within the anonymous function's scope, and the terse arrays. Thanks for the added lesson in JS. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Clear timer on "Clear"
$('input[name=clear]').click(function() {
    window.clearInterval(t);
});
```

should be

```
// Clear timer on "Clear"
$('input[name=clear]').click(function() {
    window.clearInterval(window.t);
});
```

because `this` is the input not `Window`